# Python - rgb2gray not working on my photo

Tags: python, image, rgb, grayscale

It's a bit complicated, I'll try to explain.

I have a photo on my computer, a photo of a face. I want to read that image to some matrix `X`, do some operations which I won't go into detail as it's rather complex, but in the end I should get `X=AS`

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.io as io
from skimage import color
import sklearn.decomposition as dc
X=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('/home/oria/Desktop/1.ppm'))
ica=dc.FastICA()  
S=ica.fit(np.matrix.transpose(X))
A=ica.mixing_ 
B=np.linalg.pinv(A)
S=np.dot(B,X) 
Y=np.dot(A,S)
```

The expected end result, is that Y will be approximately equal to X.
This is not the case, and I think the reason why this isn't the case is that X in a graylevel image (this is `io.imshow(X)`)

[image]

while Y is not (`io.imshow(Y)`):

[image]

You can see its the same person, same picture, which is good,but the colors are all distorted. So i thought maybe if I could transfer Y to graylevel, then I would get X=Y.

But whenever I do **`io.imshow(color.rgb2gray(Y))`**, nothing changes. And to check myself even further, `Y-color.rgb2gray(Y)` is indeed the zero matrix. It's as if rgb2gray didn't do anything.

Why isn't it working?